# SQL Server Procedure completes prematurely after converting comma-delimited value strings to XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, cross-apply

I have a procedure which executes beautifully within SSMS environment yet, when I hook it up to a web page, instead of seeing a list of packageIDs returned, the return is 'null'. I've checked permissions, which doesn't seem to be the issue. Then I ran the procedure through Profiler and it seemed to complete after the 'CAST AS XML...CROSS APPLY' statement, which would explain why nothing is returned. I can't figure out why this would be though. Any ideas?

Here is the full procedure

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

--get EVERY product in EVERY package
DECLARE @allprodsandpacks TABLE (
      packageID varchar(20),
      Name varchar(800),
      RN tinyint,
      productID varchar(20)
)


--list products in more than one package
DECLARE @prods TABLE (
      productID varchar(20),
      packages varchar(800)
)

--list packages with a 'shared' product
DECLARE @packs TABLE (
      packageID varchar(20),
      Name varchar(200),
      products varchar(800)
)



INSERT INTO @allprodsandpacks (packageID,Name,RN,productID)
SELECT  packageID,
    Name,
    RN,

    REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))),'|','') AS productID
    FROM


    (
       SELECT productID as packageID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY productlist ORDER BY productID) AS RN,
       Name,
       CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(productlist, ',', '</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
       FROM   TBOnline.dbo.Packages
    ) AS t
    CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)

--Profiler registers SP:Completed here!!


INSERT INTO @prods (productID)
SELECT DISTINCT productID
FROM @allprodsandpacks
WHERE RN > 1 


INSERT INTO @packs (packageID,Name)
SELECT DISTINCT 
packageID
, Name
FROM @allprodsandpacks    
WHERE productID IN (SELECT productID FROM @prods)

SELECT 
packageID
, Name
FROM @packs
ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: You should edit the question and include the full stored procedure definition.

Comment: You're right, @GordonLinoff , edited to show full proc now

Comment: How are you executing the script? It is possible that the rowcounts returned from the inserts are interfering with whatever is reading your results, i.e. "21 record(s) affected" is being interpreted as the first result set, therefore not returning what you are expected. Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` to the top of your script.

Comment: Good idea @GarethD but no dice. Executing in SSMS is fine and gives me what I want. Executing via a PHP function returns NULL and, as mentioned, in Profiler the query registers as Complete after the conversion of 'productlist' (a comma/pipe delimeted string to rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was not with the procedure itself but with the PHP function calling it. Prior to execution, I had to include

```
        mssql_query("SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON");
        mssql_query("SET ANSI_PADDING ON");
        mssql_query("SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON");
```

in the function. Setting these in the procedure itself had no effect.

My question, directed at the MS SQL Server community was misguided but I'll leave this here in case anyone else has this problem.